# django foreign key table fields in html template

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-templates

I have two tables(article,comment) are related one to many relashionship using a foreign  key. I would have want in the html template list  and some fields from the table one article but that I create don't work ,here the code :

models.py

```
class article(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=254)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.id)


class comment(models.Model):
    field_1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    field_2 = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    field_3 = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    field_fk= models.ForeignKey('article', blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    apps = article.objects.all()
    comments = comment.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'apps':apps,'comments':comments})
```

html template :

```
{% for b in apps %}
<p>{{ b.field_1 }}</p>
<p>{{ b.field_2 }}</p>
<p>{{ b.field_3 }}</p>
      {% for c in b.field_fk.comments %}
    <p>{{ c.name }},{{ c.last_name}},{{ c.age}}</p>
          {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

in my example in the template don't show me `name` , `last_name` and `age` is empty the paragraph

Comment: Why have you added `comments` after `field_fk`?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman tell me your proposal

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the comments using just `.comments`. Use modelname_set. In your case it would be `comments_set`. Your for-loop will look like this:

```
{% for c in b.field_fk.comment_set.all %}
    <p>{{ c.name }},{{ c.last_name}},{{ c.age}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Also, you aren't looping the correct model. `apps` is set to Article but in your template you are using the Comment fields (field_1, field_2...). The first part should be:

```
{% for article in apps %}
    <p>{{ article.name}}</p>
    <p>{{ article.last_name}}</p>
    <p>{{ article.age}}</p>
...
```

Since the article is the main loop you don't to use the foreign key. The loop should use the comment_set directly:

```
{% for comment in b.comment_set.all %}
    <p>{{ comment.field_1 }},{{ comment.field_2 }},{{ comment.field_3}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Which Django version are you using?

Comment: django version 1.11

Comment: There was a typo. I wrote `comments_set` instead of `comment_set`. It should work now.

Comment: no I saw that before ,don't work again and I don't know where is wrong :(

Comment: You have passed '`apps': apps` in the context. Apps are articles. Articles doesn't have field_1 or field_2. You should be using name, last_name and age.

Answer (score 0):

use this code

views.py :

```
def index(request):
    comments = comment.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'comments':comments})
```

HTML template :

```
{% for b in comments %}
<p>{{ b.field_1 }}</p>
<p>{{ b.field_2 }}</p>
<p>{{ b.field_3 }}</p>
<p>{{ b.field_fk.name }},{{ b.field_fk.last_name}},{{ b.field_fk.age}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: When you include code blocks in the answer, please use the appropriate formatting. See stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code